# Как найти количество Many to many related обьектов с фильтром в Django?

Tags: django

```
    в БД есть две таблицы, студент и оценка. Мне нужно узнать количество оценок с value>90 у студента. 
    
    class Student(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        second_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        marks = models.ManyToManyField('Mark')
    
    
    class Mark(models.Model):
        value = models.IntegerField()
    
    
    def get_student_mark(request, id):
            student = get_object_or_404(Student, id__iexact=id)
// тут проблема            
            count = student.marks.filter(value>90).count()
// 
            
            return render(request, 'Groups/student_detail.html',context={'count':count})
```

Comment: Довольно сложно понять, что именно за проблема, если не запускать это у себя и не воспроизводить. Может лучше облегчить всем задачу и привести stacktrace? Как стало возможным определить, что "тут проблема"?

Comment: "unresolved reference mark"

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это в принципе сделать, написал как я попытался и все.

Comment: Вам надо пошагово учить Django, поищите в интернете бесплатные курсы и туториалы по созданию несложных приложений на django, спросите опытных товарищей. Не пытайтесь перешагнуть базовые ступени и уж тем более не надо играть в угадайку и потом спрашивать, что тут не так.

Comment: раз уже это базовое, сложно помочь? Я не новичок в Django

Comment: Тогда в чем проблемы? Все должно работать, все, что здесь неправильно: `filter(value__gt=90)`. Согласитесь, для не новичка в Django обидное упущение. Нужно больше деталей. Я ваш код потрудился воспроизвести - все работает.

Comment: ну вот теперь большое спасибо)